# Fill text box in document with quick part by using word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I want to create a macro in word that fills a text box called "Location" with a Word quick part called "Ohio". The text box is to be populated with "Ohio" if I enter the word "Ohio" in a prompt that asks "Name of location?". I asked Chat-GPT to write the code for me but when I run the macro I get a message saying the text box called "Ohio" cannot be found. I would be very grateful for any help. Thank you!

I translated a few comments by Chat-GPT from another language. Just in case there is any confusion regarding some of the comments. This is the code:

```
Sub InsertOhioInLocation()
Dim locationName As String
Dim doc As Document
Dim shape As Shape
Dim locationFound As Boolean

' Get the current document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

' Prompt for the location name
locationName = InputBox("Name of location?", "Enter the location name")

If locationName <> "" Then
    ' Search through shapes for a text box named "Location"
    locationFound = False
    For Each shape In doc.Shapes
        If shape.Type = msoTextBox And shape.Name = "Location" Then
            ' If the text box is found, insert the "Ohio" quick part
            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Ohio: " & locationName
            locationFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next shape
    
    ' If the text box is not found, display a message
    If Not locationFound Then
        MsgBox "The text box named 'Location' was not found.", vbExclamation
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

I tried asking Chat-Gpt for modifications but all the modifications it proposed were not working. I am 100 % sure the text box is called "Ohio" as can be seen when I double click on the text box and word shows the properties of the text box.